# Error while getting form data in jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I tried to submit a form using jquery ajax but i am unable to get form value in controller.

> ajax

```
$("#fdate").on("click",function(){
  var controller_function= "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/partnerdata/partnerdata/update_partnerdata_followup_date";
  var post_data = $("#form").serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type:"post",
    url:controller_function,
    data:post_data,
    success:function(data)
    {
      alert(post_data);
    }
  });
});
```

> controller

```
public function update_partnerdata_followup_date()
{   
    $this->menufunctions->loginchecking();
    $data['msg'] = '';
    $msg            = "";
    $status         =  0;
    $err_flag       = 0;
    $status_arr     = array();
    $eco_compr_arr  = array();
    $ecoid          = 0;
    $subeco_id      = 0;
    $val_eco_id     = "";
    $val_sub_eco_id = "";
    $subecoid       = "";

    $check_id = $this->input->post('hidsubmit');
    $fromtype =  $this->input->post('fromtype');
    $datee =  $this->input->post('hddate');
    $pageNum  = $this->input->post('pageNum');


          $inputdata['followup_date'] = $this->input->post('followup_date');
          $inputdata['remarks'] = $this->input->post('remarks');
          $inputdata['val_modified_by'] =$this->session->userdata('user_id');
          $inputdata['val_modified_on'] =  date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 
          $inputdata['hid_check_id']= $check_id;


        $update = $this->partnerdata_model->update_db_row_date($inputdata);  

        if($update==1){
          $msg =  'Updated Successfully';
          $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', $msg); 
        }                            
        redirect('partnerdata/partnerdata/view_partnerdata_calender/'.$datee);               


}
```

Comment: Help us: What error(s) are you seeing?

Comment: no errors are seen but i cant access the values from the form

Comment: Have you used the developer tools of your browser to debug? See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools or https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools

Comment: yes there no errors are seen

Comment: just add your html form code

Comment: Add this Script to your ajax function after the `success` scope, and post if there is a result : `error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('Failure : '+errorThrown);
      }`

Answer (score 1):

```
 $("#fdate").submit(function(event) {

            event.preventDefault();

            var hidsubmit = $("input#hidsubmit").val();

            var fromtype = $("input#fromtype").val();

            var hddate = $("input#hddate").val();

            jQuery.ajax({


``type: "POST",

url: "<?php echo base_url('index.php/partnerdata/partnerdata/update_partnerdata_followup_date');?>",

dataType: 'json',

data: {hidsubmit: hidsubmit, fromtype: fromtype,hddate:hddate},
                success: function() {

                    //do alert

                }
            });
        });
    });
//Controller-----

  public function update_partnerdata_followup_date()

     {
        $data=array(

'hidsubmit'=>$this->input->post('hidsubmit'),

'fromtype'=>$this->input->post('fromtype'),

'hddate'=>$this->input->post('hddate')
        );


 $this->partnerdata_model->update_db_row_date($data);

}
```

//This Should run also share your model
//also check url it does not seem to be right it has duplicate names

Comment: function update_db_row_date($inputdata){
        $this->db->trans_start();
        $sql = "UPDATE tg_partner_data SET 
                followup_date = '".$this->db->escape_str($inputdata['followup_date'])."'
                WHERE partner_data_id = '".$this->db->escape_str($inputdata['hid_check_id'])."'";
        $this->db->query($sql);
        $this->db->trans_complete(); 
    }